# unable to start embedded container maven spring boot

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a problem with running the spring boot project. it failed to run. the error showing:

```
2017-12-07 13:55:54.639  INFO 8624 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2a5c8d3f: startup date [Thu Dec 07 13:55:54 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-07 13:55:54.842  INFO 8624 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-12-07 13:55:54.881  INFO 8624 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3f6c3e5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-12-07 13:55:55.240  INFO 8624 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2017-12-07 13:55:56.317  WARN 8624 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/hpx-delivery-report/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-12-07 13:55:56.318  INFO 8624 --- [           main] c.p.i.m.s.b.uniqueid.EPolicyApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-07 13:55:56.327  INFO 8624 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3dd1dc90: startup date [Thu Dec 07 13:55:56 ICT 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2a5c8d3f
2017-12-07 13:55:57.518  INFO 8624 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=781352cf-bed8-31d9-a952-be1fa48d68a0
2017-12-07 13:55:57.537  INFO 8624 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-12-07 13:55:57.635  INFO 8624 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7dcc0e8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-12-07 13:55:57.671  INFO 8624 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3f6c3e5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-12-07 13:55:57.676  WARN 8624 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
2017-12-07 13:55:57.683  INFO 8624 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-07 13:55:57.690 ERROR 8624 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.prudential.integration.middleware.spring.boot.uniqueid.EPolicyApplication.main(EPolicyApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

before it, I have javax.servlet.api dependency but I think this is the problem, so I remove that dependencies but when I try to run spring boot project, still failed. I also exclude starter tomcat dependencies but still failed. I also see the solution with same problem in stackoverflow too but I can't find the solution.

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.prudential.integration.middleware.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>hpx-aws-letter-unique-id</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>hpx-aws-letter-unique-id</name>
    <description>Hpx Aws Letter Unique Id Service Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <swagger.version>2.7.0</swagger.version>
        <jboss.home>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</jboss.home>
        <config.server>http://10.170.49.103/configserver</config.server>
        <spring-cloud.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jmnarloch</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- JBOSS maven plugin to simulate deployment to JBOSS -->
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>  
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>7.9.Final</version>  
                <configuration>
                    <jbossHome>${jboss.home}</jbossHome>
                    <serverArgs>
                        <serverArg>-Dspring.profiles.active=${run.profiles}</serverArg>
                        <serverArg>-Dspring.cloud.config.uri=${config.server}</serverArg>
                    </serverArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 

            <!-- QueryDSL Generator -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>               
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hpx")
@Api(value="hpx", description="HPX Web Service")
public class HPXController {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HPXController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String tesMethod(){
        return "testing method";
    }
}
```

my configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EPolicyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EPolicyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

servlet:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(EPolicyApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add code to your post

Comment: okay I add the java code

Comment: According to the POM you supplied in your question you are **excluding** tomcat (see the <exclusion/> for spring-boot-starter-tomcat within spring-boot-starter-web).

Comment: because I want build that project to war and deploy to jboss eap. before it, I want to test with mvn spring-boot:run .. but when I clear the exclusion, still same error.. any solution?

Comment: You need spring-boot maven plugin to run it like that.

Comment: check this https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

Comment: I already try with add the plugin but still cannot call the controller, I will updating my new pom in my question..

Answer (score 2):

You need spring boot maven plugin to run it using mvn spring-boot:run. Please add below plugin to your pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also make the tomcat dependency as provided so that it wont be added in the war.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You can modify the goal as per your requirement or remove it.
Then with embedded tomcat you test your application with above commands. To deploy it to external app server you need to package it as a war and copy it to specific directory of your App server (i.e. Jboss EAP).

Comment: you have excluded the tomcat dependency. So your application wont get servlet implemenation

Comment: when I add the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependencies, I had clear the exclusion.. so still failed